# Can one earn reputation on Physics Meta?

Tags: discussion, reputation, meta

My question got upvoted on Meta but I got no reputation for that. All of my questions which got upvoted on Phy.SE gave me reputation. Any plausible reason for that not happening in this case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Meta is for discussion and support for the main site, and questions and answers here are not based on physical expertise.

Thus, you don't get any reputation here (but you also don't lose reputation for getting downvoted).

This is the case for all per-site-metas, cf. [this meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136091/263383). Meta.SE is the only meta-like site on the network which has reputation.

Comment: Though you can earn badges!

Comment: It would be cool to have a separate rep pool though... Some of us may be brilliant governors but not great physicists. And I believe we have all come across people who were the exact opposite.